# AWS boto3 rightsizing recommendations cost explorer , how to export the csv with lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto3

client = boto3.client('ce')
response = client.get_rightsizing_recommendation(Service='AmazonEC2')

The above request timed out after 15mins

What is the best practice to filter the underutilized instances in ec2 and upload the csv to s3 bucket ?

Comment: Can you post the error message to be clear of what the error is...and also check if you have mfa enabled in your aws account, you must add token to credentials.

Answer (score 0):

filtering is based on requirement. As per [API documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ce.html#CostExplorer.Client.get_rightsizing_recommendation) you can see quite number of options available e.g based on region, dimension etc.

NOTE: I'm not eligible to add comment so added this as answer.